# Why does my Swing main thread die?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, swing, maven

Morning,

I'm facing a strange problem with Java - Swing.
This is my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    PrincipalWindow windowImportLoadCurve = new PrincipalWindow();
                    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    setModelViewTable(windowImportLoadCurve);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Running it from inside Eclipse IDE (Neon 2.0). It creates 4 threads

```
Daemon Thread [AWT-Windows] (Running)   
Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)    -> Main
Thread [AWT-Shutdown] (Running) 
Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Running)
```

Its runs normally and works, the JVM just close when the GUI application finishes. So I genereted a jar using Maven Install with external dependencies

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>weblogic-client-unpack</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>                              
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jboss-client-unpack</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>                   
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ingrid-load-generator-package-assembly</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>main.MainGenerator</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly-bin.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And started running using a bat. The same application creates the same 4 Threads, so it opens the GUI (with the SwingUtility.invokeLater() Thread) and keep running the main. But when the GUI is actually open, it immediately closes without any user action.

Comment: Why are you using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to do all your setup code? What happens if you do it directly from `main()`?

Comment: @Thomas Because it should be done that way. Read docs.

Comment: @Thomas That's how it's supposed to be done : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: Huh, thanks, TIL. I actually did look up a Swing tutorial and it didn't do this. I stand corrected (and so does that tutorial). It's been about 15 years since I touched Swing myself...

Answer (score 1):

My first guess was wrong.

Try creating/posting a minimal code example using only swing components that shows the behavior you are seeing.

Here is an example that works for me:

```
public class Test {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame jf=new JFrame("Hi");
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            JF.setSize(500,200);
            jf.setVisible(true);
}});}}
```

If this doesn't work for you, it's something to do with your environment.  If it does work for you, use it as a starting point and start converting it to be more like your code, running tests after each change.  When you find the change that broke it, you have your answer.

Comment: I've inserted the Thread.sleep(10000L); at the end of the main, and the GUI opne waits for 10 seconds and closes. I've changed the from invokeLater to invokeAndWait and nothing chaged. 

How can I put a join() in a SwingUtilities thread?? Or the wait ??

Comment: The GUI open, so the visible is enable and the sysout is not necessary. I've changed from SwingUitilities to a common Thread to trya dn it still worked

Comment: And you don't get a printed stack Trace?  Is there any chance you code had an empty catch statement somewhere?  Either that or a system.exit?  If the window is displayed your app shouldn't exit.

Comment: Yeah :( No exception, i ran it in debug mode line per line and nothing... The mais thread just finishes and closes the JVM.

Comment: Yes, running in a remote debug, I can see the Window open and use her while the main Thread is stopped in a breakpoint, but when I realease de BP the Window close and the JVM finishes

Comment: What if you have the 10 second sleep in the main thread?  Does the window vanish at the beginning of the 10 seconds or at the end?  I'm currently thinking your window is crashing immediately after being created allowing the main() to exit after the 10 seconds is up (Rather than exiting main() causing your window to be destroyed).

Comment: The window open fand stay for 10 seconds then close. During this 10 seconds I can work with it normally, passing the sleep time everything shutsdown

Comment: You should try it with a "Normal" window.  Just make a JFrame and call .setVisible on it.  let me know if THAT exits when your main thread exits--at least we could come up with a failing code sample I could run--that way we could compare behavior.